# How to got put params from config file to a single module?

Tags: haskell

I have a program have to read params from config file when the program start.In other language,I create a module,or class,called Params,when the program start,I use Params.set to set the params read from config file,and at any place,when I need to use the params,I use Params.get to read the value of the params

but in haskell,because there is no varaible,so it seems I have to read the params from the main function,then put all of it to a record,for example,named Params,then use the record Params as the function's param and pass it to every function that use the params form config file.I think it's ulgy.I have no idea of how to put the param values to a seperate module or file

Is there some way to resolve this?Thanks!

Comment: Implicit parameters and the "implicit configurations" paper might be some help.

Comment: In my experience, _explicitly_ passing dependencies the "ugly" way you describe is a best practice, in _every_ programming language.  "I import this module and my dependencies magically appear" makes it very hard to tell what the dependencies actually are and how you interact with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way to pass a global state in Haskell is with a [Reader](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html) type.  Then you can access your `Params` with [ask](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#v:ask) when needed.

This is quite similar to passing the `Params` explicitly, and that's also a fine choice.